# Why does PsExec hang after successfully running a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, pstools

The script is fairly straight forward.  Simply tries to start a bunch of windows services.  Execution locally works fine when on the target machine.  The script is actually executing fine as well when done via PsExec, it just never returns until I hit the "enter" key on my CMD prompt.  This is a problem, because this is being called from TeamCity, and it makes the Agent hang waiting for PsExec to return.

I've tried the following:

- Adding an `exit` and `exit 0` at the end of the Powershell script
- Adding a `< NUL` to the end of the PsExec call, per the answer in **[this SF question](https://serverfault.com/a/151881/18496)**
- Adding a `>` stdout redirect

This is how I am actually calling psexec:

```
psexec \\target -u domain\username -p password powershell c:\path\script.ps1
```

No matter what I do, it hangs until I the  locally on the cmd prompt.  After I hit enter, I get the message:

```
powershell exited on target with error code 0.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out this is a common problem.  Found the solution a [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/10/02/using-powershell-and-psexec-to-invoke-expressions-on-remote-computers/).  Essentially, if you pipe some data on stdin with cmd it will return propertly after execution (because it is being run via cmd, not powershell).

Example:

```
psexec \\target -u domain\username -p password cmd /c "echo . | powershell c:\path\script.ps1"
```

Comment: is it set up as Command Line - Custom Script or Command Line - Executable (in TeamCity)?

Comment: OK Ive set it up as Executable and it helped. Thanks mate I've spent 1 day diagnosing it. Spread the word!

Comment: After a day the problem returned...

Answer (score 14):

I know the answer comes late it would have already been figured out, If not it might be useful for future visitors.

STDIN has to be re-directed in powershell execution inorder to be able to come from hang (Here it waits in STDIN). to be able to do this use -inputformat none

`powershell -inputformat none -File powershell_script.ps1` will work.

Check - https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/572313/powershell-exe-can-hang-if-stdin-is-redirected

Comment: Not only does this work, but it also explains why the accepted answer works. Thanks!

Comment: -inputformat none -- this is not a valid parameter in v.2.43

Answer (score 4):

```
psexec \\target -u domain\username -p password -d powershell c:\path\script.ps1
```

Also fixes the problem.

The [`-d` flag for psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) is like "run and exit" in a non-interactive way:

> -d Don’t wait for the application to terminate.
>
> Only use for non-interactive applications.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is not exiting.  Try this command line

```
Powershell -command script.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running `psexec` with VBS script and the solution marked as the best (EX: `psexec \\target -u domain\username -p password cmd /c "echo . | powershell c:\path\script.ps1"`) was working for me only during each 3rd or so run. I was keep digging and I found [description of each switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

I decided to try "-s" and that what worked for me every single time
Here is my example:

```
call C:\psexec.exe %SERVER_NAME% -u %USERNAME% -p %PASSWORD% -h -s cscript %pathTomyVBSscript%
```